# How can I change the name of the attached PDF document before sending?

Tags: livecycle-designer

I have form that attaches the full pdf to an outgoing email when the 'Submit' button is selected. By default attachment is name of the form. I want to rename the attachment.

I am using AEM 6.3 Designer.